# JSON stringify not to parse my setter function

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension, getter-setter

I got the next code with some getters and setters done this way so I can hide the parameters.

```
// trackedWebsite: does not use the new to create the object trackedWebsite. 
//Creates an object with private parameters only accessible by the getter 

var trackedWebsite = function(url,extensions){
return {
        //This returns the URL of the website
        get get_URL() {
            return url;
        },

        get get_Extensions(){
            return extensions;
        },

        set set_Extensions(ext){
            this.extensions = ext;
        }


    }

}
```

At some point, I want to save the information an array of trackedWebsite called websites in localStorage, so I parse it with JSON:

```
localStorage.websites=JSON.stringify(websites);
```

Finally at some point I load all the websites again:

```
function getAllWebsites(){
if (localStorage.websites === undefined){
    return new Array();
}
return JSON.parse(localStorage.websites);
```

}

When I do this, the get functions work properly, but I find that the trackedWebsites in the array i receive back does not include the setter. When I try to use it, I get: Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'set_Extensions' . Why does this happen? Why does the getter works properly but not the setter?

EDIT: 
Added the code where the setter is invoked

```
            websites[index].set_Extensions(extensions);
```

Thank you

Comment: You use a setter like `obj.set_Extensions = value`. You are obviously calling it like a method `obj.set_Extensions()` though

Comment: where is the code where you are using the setter method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not just your setter that's broken, but also your getter. After serializing your object to a JSON string, the result is something like

```js
{"get_URL":"http://....","get_Extensions":["extension1","extension2"]}
```

If you really want to reconstruct the original object, use

```js
function getAllWebsites() {
    if (localStorage.websites === undefined){
        return [];
    }
    var parsedJSON = JSON.parse(localStorage.websites);
    // Assume that parsedJSON is an array
    return parsedJSON.map(function(website) {
        return trackedWebsite(website.get_URL, website.get_Extensions);
    });
}
```

You can define a custom JSON serialization and parsing method if you need more flexibility - see [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

---

There's another issue with your code. It's not idiomatic, because your getters/setters are prefixed with `set_` and `get_`. Your "trackedWebsite" object works as follows, at the moment:

```js
var url = website.get_URL;
website.set_Extensions = ...;
var extensions = website.get_Extensions;
```

This should actually be

```js
var url = website.URL;               // Being at the right side implies getter
website.extensions = ...;            // Assignment implies setter
var extensions = website.extensions; // Being at the right side implies getter
```

Or at the very least:

```js
var url = website.get_URL();
website.set_Extensions(...);
var extensions = website.get_Extensions();
```

Comment: the way i've done the getters work as i am already using them properly in my code. I am doing it that way so I have the url and the extension encapsulated, so you need to call the get_Extension and the set_Extension to modify it. But I understand that there is a problem with the .set_Extensions as I am colling it without the (). Isn't it obvious that I come from java? :D

Comment: Your code doesn't need (). What I'm suggesting are alternative ways to achieve the intended effect in an idiomatic way. I've left out the (trivial) implementation details.